# Invisible subfolder under AppData

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winui-3

I'm working on a project that involves the rewriting of legacy Windows applications for a modern .NET environment. The structure of these applications requires that there is one "Master" application running locally on the user's machine that fetches the others from a network share, along with required DLLs, and then runs them locally. This is not a problem per se, but I'm running into issues when I try to use the current user's AppData folder structure for this, whether it's local or roaming.

Thing is though, I can create a subfolder without a problem, I can copy files over (via a call to System.IO.File.Copy) and run them (via creating and starting an instance of System.Diagnostics.Process), but still the applications complain that they can't find the needed DLLs. This probably is related to the fact that the subfolder doesn't show up in the file system at all, which leads me to believe that files are not being copied over there in a fully conventional sense, but rather exist in some sort of limbo that prevents them from being "aware" of each other. When I do the copying and running to a standard filesystem folder, it all works fine. I've been trying to Google this issue as I was sure that this was a known problem, but I'm having a hard time finding anything on this subject. Hence this question.

Any ideas as to what might be going on? Or is my approach of using AppData for this particular purpose perhaps misguided to begin with?

EDIT: Comments asked for a viable code sample that reproduces the problem. I did have some interesting results trying to reproduce the issue as simply as I could. I created a fresh console app and could not reproduce it there. I then tried a fresh WinUI 3 app (which is what I'm trying to work with for my project) and I reproduced it there - the code seems to create the directory and then the file, without complaints (I run without the subfolder being there), but they don't show up in Explorer. For comparison, I then tried a fresh WPF app that does the exact same thing but this behaves the same as the console app, no issue with the subfolder and file showing up after running the app. So my issue seems to be confined to WinUI only.

You should be able to reproduce by placing this code inside the main window of a fresh application (and creating a button called myButton if VS doesn't do that automatically) and comparing WinUI 3 with WPF.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information

        var destinationPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "Subfolder");
        string sourceFilename = "C:\\Data\\Textfile.txt";

        CopyFileToLocalExecutionPath(sourceFilename, destinationPath);
    }

    private string CopyFileToLocalExecutionPath(string sourceFilename, string destinationPath)
    {
        // Make sure that destination path exists before copying file
        if (!Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);

        // Assign full destination filename - local path + same as source filename
        var destinationFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sourceFilename));

        // Do not overwrite file if it's already there
        if (!File.Exists(destinationFilename))
            File.Copy(sourceFilename, destinationFilename);

        return destinationFilename;
    }
```

Comment: Is the problem that files are not copied? If so, please provide a [mre] that shows how you are copying the files - especially how you are listing which files to copy. [`Directory.GetFiles(String, String, EnumerationOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-6.0#system-io-directory-getfiles(system-string-system-string-system-io-enumerationoptions)) allows you to choose which files to list.

Comment: 100% we need to see a code snippet which exhibits this problem to understand if this is a programmatic issue or something else going on.

Comment: Hi, I definitely should have tried reproducing first and comparing environments. The issue seems to be confined to WinUI 3. See my edit. Maybe I need to give up on using WinUI, I've been running into other issues with it anyway. It might just not be ready for prime time.